# Change type of an Input element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change type of input, specifically after click into input I need to change `type="text"` to `type="date"`.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="DOB" id="dob" name="dob" />
<script>
    $("#dob").click(function () {
        $(this).attr('type', 'date');

    });
</script>
```

I want to accomplish this for a iphone App. This is not working in iphone 4. How can do this?

Comment: Can I ask you reason for wanting to do this? I am pretty sure there must be a better way.

Comment: In iphone 4 the placeholder doesnot show for input type dat. So I want to change the type after clicking the field

Comment: Better have two input fields and hide the text field and show the date field on click event.

Comment: You don't need a placeholder on a date input - they come with widgets to do the formatting for you. The problem is that you appear to be using the placeholder as a replacement for a `<label>` which the specification is very explicit that you should not do.

Comment: *[The placeholder attribute should not be used as an alternative to a label.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute)* and *The placeholder attribute represents a short hint (a word or short phrase) intended to aid the user with data entry. A hint could be a sample value or a brief description of the expected format.*

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use this code :

```
<input type="text" placeholder="DOB" id="dob" name="dob"  />
<script>
   $("#dob").click(function(){
        $(this).prop('type', 'date');

  });
</script>
```

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/HNKkW/

Answer (score 7):

It's a property, so [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) will do it :

```
$("#dob").on('click', function(){
     $(this).prop('type', 'date');
});​
```

And remember to wrap that in a document.ready function !

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMhLP/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Earlier version of Jquery

```
$('body').delegate('#dob','click',function(){
            $(this).attr('type', 'date');

      });
```

Or if you use latest see @adeno 's answer

Answer (score 0):

**See this working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqhC2/).**

You can't change the type of an input due to restrictions in the browser using `.attr`. Note this warning you receive from the console:

```
Uncaught Error: type property can't be changed
```

You can change the type by using [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop)

```
$("#dob").on('click', function(){
    $(this).prop('type', 'date');
});​
```

I think there may be a bit of an underlying problem here. Would the user not be confused by the type of text-box changing?

If at all possible you should try and change the type of the text-box before showing it to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct solution for your problem is using the **.focus** and the **.prop** properties.

```
<script>
    $("#dob").focus(function () {
        $(this).prop('type', 'date');

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

for me using ***prop*** directly on the element was not working, this however worked for me after a lot of fiddling, so I wanted to share and maybe save someone the headache.

```
$(document).on('change', '#showPass', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parents('form').find('#passField').prop("type", "text");
    } else {
        $(this).parents('form').find('#passField').prop("type", "password");
    }
});
```